Antd tabs: scrollable div with flex: 1 1 0 without having to override Ant classes
I am using the Antd Tabs component. Inside the content of Tab 2 I have a container with two divs, header and results. The results div is scrollable and has a dynamic height (e.g. if the header height changes it will resize).
The only way I can currently get this to work is if I override some Antd classes with display: flex instead of display: block (which I would like to avoid).
Is there any way to achieve the same behaviour without having to override the Antd classes in this case? Or without using flex?
Codepen: https://codepen.io/jgredecka/pen/PorpeRg
